# Django user proxy models fast access

Tags: django, proxy, models

I have proxy model for user:

```
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

How can i get it in templates without pass from view? can i get it only from request.user instance?

I am using template context processor for this:

```
def m_processor(request):
    from main.models import MyUser
    mu = MyUser.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
    return {'meuser':mu}

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'settings.m_processor',
    )
```

Better solution exsists?

Answer (score 1):

In your view, when you return render_to_response, you can add context_instance = RequestContext(request).

```
return render_to_response("template_name", "vars_dict", context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

This will make the variable request accessible from the template